# Why I am in the top 4 positions of the Parity txqueue? (not local)

Tags: transactions, parity, dapps, pending-transactions

I've been wondering why none of my transactions have been going through. Now, I understand the network has been overloaded from the status.im ICO but it seems odd that I would show up in the top 4 of (global?) Parity transactions waiting. Curious.

I actually made more transactions that this but somehow they disappeared. (about 5) I've tried with various gas prices, but don't want they all to go through at the same time (as some are duplicates)

using Parity//v1.6.8-beta-c396229-20170608/x86_64-windows-msvc/rustc1.17.0

Block count is #3,907,434, which is current

peers: 0/11/25

Any ideas?[image: stuck in the queue]

Answer (score 1):

It just pins your transactions at the top for better visibility. If you scroll up (not visible in your screenshot), you see the status of all your transactions. They are either queued (pending), replaced, mined, or invalid.

There should be nothing missing. Note that all the green transactions in your screenshot are **not** duplicates. They will be executed as soon as miner accept them into any block. Once broadcasted, you can't cancel transactions anymore.

Comment: Thanks. What I mean by that is the last column, 1120 (107 peers). This is the highest out of all in the list. And I have 4 of those. First propagation was 399.5 minutes ago. Is that normal?
  
Yes, the green ones aren't duplicates but out of more than 10 that were created about 5-6 are now nowhere to be found on etherscan.

Comment: Ah, yes, miners largely ignore the order in which transactions were broadcasted. They only look at gas price and check if they can squeeze in some other transactions with lower gas limit if possible.

Comment: Average in the list seems to be abotu 0.2, but my first one has 1.580 MGas. I guess I'll try another one with more gas. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Just did another transaction with maximum gas (at the time) and in etherscan the hash says 'Unable to locate Transaction entry' and it doesn't show up in my transaction list. Definitely something else going on, I think.

Comment: Don't confuse gas price with gas limit. High gas limit usually takes longer to get included because there is often not enough space in the blocks.